# Powershell Filter for mathing AD Account to Folder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to match the samaccountname to the current folder patch, and it would worked fine if the folderpatch was "d:\profile\username" but instead of username its states username_S-1-5-21*....

I use the below code, but is it possible to filter everything behind the _S-1.... so it can match the username to the samaccountname ?

I use the below code, any help would be appreciated

[EDIT: added complete script]

Below is the complete script, so the issue is that i have several user folder with _S-1-5-21* behind the username in the folder of our FXLogic profile folder and need to match the samaccountname with the folder ( username - _S-1-5-21* )

I hope this explanation is more clear, and yes its a SID not a GUID always get them mixed up.

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
$FXLogicFolderPath,
$MoveFolderPath,
$SearchBase,
[string[]]$ExcludePath,
[switch]$FolderSize,
[switch]$MoveDisabled,
[switch]$DisplayAll,
[switch]$UseRobocopy,
[switch]$RegExExclude,
[switch]$CheckFXLogicDirectory)
```

## Check if FXLogicFolderPath is found, exit with warning message if path is incorrect

```
if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $FXLogicFolderPath)){
Write-Warning "FXLogicFolderPath not found: $FXLogicFolderPath"
```

## Check if MoveFolderPath is found, exit with warning message if path is incorrect

```
if ($MoveFolderPath) {
if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $MoveFolderPath)){
    Write-Warning "MoveFolderPath not found: $MoveFolderPath"
    exit
}}
exit
```

## Main loop, for each folder found under FXLogic folder path AD is queried to find a matching samaccountname

```
$ListOfFolders = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "$FXLogicFolderPath" -Force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}
```

## Exclude folders if the ExcludePath parameter is given

```
if ($ExcludePath) {
$ExcludePath | ForEach-Object {
    $CurrentExcludePath = $_
    if ($RegExExclude) {
        $ListOfFolders = $ListOfFolders | Where-Object {$_.FullName -notmatch $CurrentExcludePath}
    } else {
        $ListOfFolders = $ListOfFolders | Where-Object {$_.FullName -ne $CurrentExcludePath}
    }
}}

$ListOfFolders | ForEach-Object {
$CurrentPath = Split-Path -Path $_ -Leaf
```

## Construct AD Searcher, add SearchRoot attribute if SearchBase parameter is specified

```
    $ADSearcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher -Property @{
    Filter = "(samaccountname=$CurrentPath)"
}
if ($SearchBase) {
    $ADSearcher.SearchRoot = [adsi]$SearchBase
}
```

## Use the FullName path to look for a FXLogicdirectory attribute and replace the backslash by the \5C LDAP escape character

```
    if ($CheckFXLogicDirectory) {
    $ADSearcher.Filter = "(FXLogicdirectory=$($_.FullName -replace '\\','\5C')*)"
}
```

## Execute AD Query and store in $ADResult

```
$ADResult = $ADSearcher.Findone()
```

## If no matching samaccountname is found this code is executed and displayed

```
    if (!($ADResult)) {
    $HashProps = @{
        'Error' = 'Account does not exist and has a FXLogic folder'
        'FullPath' = $_.FullName
    }
    if ($FolderSize) {
        $HashProps.SizeinBytes = [long](Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Exp Sum)
        $HashProps.SizeinMegaBytes = "{0:n2}" -f ($HashProps.SizeinBytes/1MB)
    }
    
    if ($MoveFolderPath) {
        $HashProps.DestinationFullPath = Join-Path -Path $MoveFolderPath -ChildPath (Split-Path -Path $_.FullName -Leaf)
        if ($UseRobocopy) {
            robocopy $($HashProps.FullPath) $($HashProps.DestinationFullPath) /E /MOVE /R:2 /W:1 /XJD /XJF | Out-Null
        } else {
            Move-Item -LiteralPath $HashProps.FullPath -Destination $HashProps.DestinationFullPath -Force
        }
    }
```

## Output the object

```
New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $HashProps
```

## If samaccountname is found but the account is disabled this information is displayed

```
} elseif (([boolean]((-join $ADResult.Properties.useraccountcontrol) -band 2))) {
    $HashProps = @{
        'Error' = 'Account is disabled and has a FXLogic folder'
        'FullPath' = $_.FullName
    }
    if ($FolderSize) {
        $HashProps.SizeinBytes = [long](Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Exp Sum)
        $HashProps.SizeinMegaBytes = "{0:n2}" -f ($HashProps.SizeinBytes/1MB)
    }

    if ($MoveFolderPath -and $MoveDisabled) {
        $HashProps.DestinationFullPath = Join-Path -Path $MoveFolderPath -ChildPath (Split-Path -Path $_.FullName -Leaf)
        Move-Item -LiteralPath $HashProps.FullPath -Destination $HashProps.DestinationFullPath -Force
    }
```

## Output the object

```
New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $HashProps
```

## Folders that do have active user accounts are displayed if -DisplayAll switch is set

```
} elseif ($ADResult -and $DisplayAll) {
    $HashProps = @{
        'Error' = $null
        'FullPath' = $_.FullName
    }
    if ($FolderSize) {
        $HashProps.SizeinBytes = [long](Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Exp Sum)
        $HashProps.SizeinMegaBytes = "{0:n2}" -f ($HashProps.SizeinBytes/1MB)
    }
```

## Output the object

```
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $HashProps
}}







# Construct AD Searcher, add SearchRoot attribute if SearchBase parameter is specified

$ADSearcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher -Property @{
    Filter = "(samaccountname=$CurrentPath)"
}
if ($SearchBase) {
    $ADSearcher.SearchRoot = [adsi]$SearchBase
```

Answer (score 2):

The `S-1-5-21...` part is not a GUID, it's a **SID** (the principal's **S**ecurity **Id**entifier).

You can use the `-replace` operator to remove that part of the folder name:

```
$folderName = 'username_S-1-5-21-2855571654-3033049851-1520320983-9328'
$userName = $folderName -replace '_S-1-5.*$'
```

After which you can construct the desired LDAP query filter:

```
$ADSearcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher -Property @{
    Filter = "(samaccountname=$userName)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your username is being derived from but you could do something simple with a regex replace on the `$CurrentPath`

```
$currentPath = 'username_S-1-5-21-2855571654-3033049851-1520320983-9328'
$currentPath = $currentPath -replace '_.+'

# AD Searcher here
```

This will replace everything after the underscore but all usernames will have to be in a consistent format or you'll have to take into account all possible formats that could be encountered.